# Amazon Linux: "apt-get: command not found"

Tags: linux, apt, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install an [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) server on my AWS instance. However, it seems that it doesn't have the apt package installed.

I googled and all I found was some broken links to this package. I am using [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) on a Windows machine if that information helps.

I currently have low to none experience in Linux environments.

I am running the following version of Linux:

```
Linux ip-172-31-37-96 3.14.48-33.39.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 14 23:43:07 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: When creating the server in the EC2 dashboard, choose "ubuntu linux" as the server type.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

If you're using Amazon Linux it's CentOS-based, which is RedHat-based. RH-based installs use `yum` not `apt-get`. Something like `yum search httpd` should show you the available Apache packages - you likely want `yum install httpd24`.

> Note: Amazon Linux 2 has [diverged from CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/798427/what-linux-distribution-is-the-amazon-linux-ami-based-on) since the writing of this answer, but still uses `yum`.

Comment: Add -y to yum to avoid yum prompting question to your script.

Comment: Adding to Steven's comment -> `yum -y install <package name>`

Comment: @Asif Why would you ask that here, in the comments of a six year old thread about something else entirely?

Answer (score 29):

Try to install your application by using a [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software)) command:

`yum install application_name`

Answer (score 7):

Check the Linux distribution. `apt-get` works in a [Debian-based distribution](https://www.debian.org/misc/children-distros) whereas `yum` works in a [Fedora-based distribution](https://distrowatch.com/search.php?basedon=Fedora#simple).

[Ref: How to know the distribution name](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/). Execute command `cat /etc/*-release`

It is also possible your system administrator does not permit you (or did not put you in the group of users who have `sudo` permissions) to execute `apt-get`, but if you have `sudo` access, try to execute with `sudo apt-get <package_name>` if Debian or `yum install <package_name>` if you are using [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29).

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue regarding `apt-get: command not found`. Here are the steps how I resolved it on [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus):

- Search the appropriate version of **apt** from [here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/)
  (`apt_1.6.13_amd64.deb` for Ubuntu 16.04)
- Download the apt.deb

`wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.6.13_amd64.deb`

- Install the apt.deb package

`sudo dpkg -i apt_1.6.13_amd64.deb`

Now we can easily run

`sudo apt-get install htop`

Comment: This URL is broken?

Comment: use http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.8.1_i386.deb

Comment: instead just [go here](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/) and search for the version and distro, avoiding waiting for URL to broke

Comment: wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.9.4_amd64.deb

Comment: Latest is http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.3.9_amd64.deb

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for complete AWS beginners:

I had this issue, but it was because I was trying to run a command from a tutorial inside my Mac computer. I actually needed to SSH into my AWS machine, and then run the same command there. Ta Da, it worked:

[image]

Click this button in your EC2 instance, to be able to copy the SSH command. Set up your SSH keys (*"[Amazon EC2 key pairs and Linux instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html)"*) and then you can SSH into your machine.

Once here, you can run your `sudo apt-get` command.

Answer (score 2):

There can be two issues:

1. Your are trying the command on a machine that does not support the `apt-get` command
   because `apt-get` is only suitable for Linux-based [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) machines; for Mac, try
   the `apt-get` equivalent such as [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`)
2. The other issue can be that your installation was not completed properly, so:

#### The short answer

Reinstall Ubuntu from a [live CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) or [USB stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive).

#### The long version:

The long version would be a waste of your time: your system will never be clean, but if you insist you could try:

Copying everything (missing), except for the */home* folder, from the live CD or USB to your hard disk drive.

*Or*

Do a reinstall or repair over the broken system again with the live CD or USB stick.

*Or*

Download the .deb file for `apt-get` and install as explained in the previous posts.

I would definitely go for a fresh new install as there are so many things to do and so little time.

Answer (score 1):

> apt–get: command not found

For Debian based Linux distributions:

Try to use `sudo apt install <package>` instead of the usual `sudo apt-get install <package>`

From [`man apt`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.8.en.html)

> apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).

Answer (score 1):

Use [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software)) with sudo for *Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type*.

Example: Try to install [WSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) with Apache at an AWS instance:

```
sudo yum install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Comment: How to install `Font 'Arial'`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually download the [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)) .deb package. Then run [dpkg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) and it should install.

Comment: I went to https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt and there are a list of options: squeeze (oldoldstable), squeeze-lts, wheezy (oldstable), jessie (stable) and experimental (rc-buggy) that are not listed as unstable or testing. Which one should I get?

Comment: None of them. There's no reason to install apt on an Amazon Linux server.

Comment: Yeah. I totally skipped over the word AWS. That's not a Debian server. Go with ceejayoz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the commands which you can run to install `apt-get`:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

For an [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) Linux distribution:

```
sudo zypper install <package>
```

For example:

```
sudo zypper install git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
```

[Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) is also available on [Amazon Linux Extras](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/faqs/#Amazon_Linux_Extras).