# 'gitk' installation is not working on Linux

Tags: linux, git, github

I have successfully Git installed and running.

```
git --version
git version 2.6.1
```

I want to add [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) now. I entered the following command to install the gitk package, but it says no package available.

`sudo yum install git-gui gitk`

Returns

```
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package git-gui available.
No package gitk available.
Nothing to do
```

After that, when I type `gitk` on the command line, it throws the following error.

```
Application initialization failed: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories:
    /usr/lib/tcl8.4/tk8.4 /usr/lib/tk8.4 /local/p4clients/pkgbuild-9867w/workspace/build/TclTk/TclTk-8.4.199.32504/RHEL5_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/private/tcl/install/lib/tk8.4 /lib/tk8.4 /usr/library /library /tk8.4.12/library
This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.

Error in startup script: invalid command name "tk_setPalette"
    while executing
"tk_setPalette background $c selectColor $selc"
    (procedure "setui" line 8)
    invoked from within
"setui $uicolor"
```

**Note:** I tried `apt-get`, but it’s not working in the system. In a post I found that [YUM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(software)) is the correct one for my system.

*[Amazon Linux: apt-get: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592956/apt-get-command-not-found)*

Comment: Are you sure that you're using `yum` on Ubuntu? I haven't heard of that combo before.

Comment: i tried `apt-get` but its not working in system. in a post i found that `yum` is the correct one for my system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592956/apt-get-command-not-found

Comment: From what I've gathered, your system doesn't include a `yum` repository containing `gitk`. This may help: http://serverfault.com/a/686181/297452

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister : So you meant to say once i add those missing files , i will work ?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister : Please note that i have already installed git. Now i am trying install for gitk only

Comment: If I knew exactly how to fix it I would definitely post an answer, just trying my best to be helpful in the comments! I'm not sure if the answer I linked is strictly relevant here, but hopefully it might give you some ideas.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister : Thanks. waiting for your ideas :)

Comment: I would recommend using `git` on the command line. Perhaps also use it thru emacs (Version Control mode)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Could you please let me know how to use it through emacs ?

Answer (score 2):

Since [gitk is distributed with git](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#gitk_.28distributed_with_Git.29), I would focus on installing the right version of Tcl/Tk.

The [git-gui package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/git-gui) (even though it is not directly applicable to your Linux distribution) would use a [tk8.6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tk)  at least. It looks like your version of tk is a bit old.

```
yum install tk
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which flavour you are trying to install gitk on. But the below is the method which I have used to install gitk on [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) 7.

Get the endpoint release rpm from https://packages.endpointdev.com as below

```
cd /tmp
wget https://packages.endpointdev.com/rhel/7/os/x86_64/endpoint-repo-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
yum localinstall endpoint-repo-1.7-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install git-gui gitk
```

Change the current directory to one of your projects where the *.git* directory is there and type `gitk` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Note that the URL for the yum repository mentioned has moved to *[End Point Software Package Repositories](https://packages.endpointdev.com/)*

There are specific setup instructions for new Git on CentOS 7 at *[Installing Git 2 on CentOS 7](https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2021/12/installing-git-2-on-centos-7/)*.

Comment: Written by you, presumably. Shouldn't that be revealed? See e.g. *[What is the policy for linking to your own blog in your answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254280/what-is-the-policy-for-linking-to-your-own-blog-in-your-answers)* and *[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)*.