# Getting errro openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, openssl

I am using ubuntu and compiling gRPC but getting error on openssh:

```
gRPC/src/core/lib/security/credentials/jwt/json_token.h:25:25: fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
```

my system have following openssh version:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips  3 May 2016
```

Tried to install openssh using following command:

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

its give error `command not found`.

Comment: Perhaps the include path is not correct.

Comment: YEs looks like but I think it shoud take from system openssh installed path

Comment: in code it is give as #include <openssl/rsa.h>

Comment: Obviously, but what are the include paths?

Comment: Do you have apt installed ? What does `which apt-get` return?

Comment: apt-get is returning commad not found

Comment: That means its not installed in your system somehow. Are you using Ubuntu? `apt-get` usually comes with the distribution.

Comment: YEs I am using ubuntu in vmware  cat /etc/lsb-release  and lsb_release -a not giving ununtu version

Comment: Looks like wrong or corrupt  version of Linux. Not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `apt-get` command is not found in your system.

This might be helpful for you ([apt-get: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592956/apt-get-command-not-found/32593095)).